# regex cdata in perl file

Tags: regex, linux, perl, cdata

help me please

in terminal :

`C no longer supported in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/<host><!\[\ <-- HERE CDATA\[(.*)\]\]\></host>/`

code in my file perl

`if ($html =~ /<host><!\[\CDATA\[(.*)\]\]\><\/host>/)`

What would be the best way of approaching this?

thanks you

Comment: The best way to approach it would be to use an HTML/XML parser.

Comment: my code error please correct my code

Comment: Here, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2):

`\C` should be `C`.

Comment: This is the answer. There is an extra \ before the `CDATA`. The error message shows the precise spot of the error.